# SQL query to get null count from a column

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I want to generate a SQL query to get null count in a particular column like

```
SELECT COUNT (column) AS count 
FROM table 
WHERE column = null ;
```

This is returning 0, but I want how many null values are present in that column like

```
SELECT COUNT (column) AS count 
FROM table 
WHERE column = 'some value';
```

which returns the count of the matched records

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NULL` value is special in that you cannot use `=` with it; you must use `IS NULL` instead:

```
SELECT COUNT (*) AS count FROM table where column IS null ;
```

This is because `NULL` in SQL does not evaluate as equal to anything, including other `NULL` values. Also note the use of `*` as the argument of `COUNT`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a conditional `sum()`

```
SELECT sum(case when column is null 
                then 1 
                else 0 
           end) AS count 
FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

A different query but exact answer check it out

```
select count(*)-count(column) from table
```

---

please vote check this as answer if it helps you

Answer (score 1):

**To get exact output you can use below command as well -**

```
SELECT COUNT (*) AS count FROM table where column IS null OR column='';
```

because some times only **''** doesn't counted as NULL.